# Unable to import java class from clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

Project structure:

```
cloj\
    void2d/
        ...

    vtd.clj
    project.clj
```

vtd.clj

```clj
(import '(void2d Window))
```

project.clj

```clj
(defproject cloj "0.0.1"
  :java-source-paths ["void2d/"])
```

When I running vtd.clj, I'm getting this:

```
Execution error (ClassNotFoundException) at java.net.URLClassLoader/findClass (REPL:-1).
void2d.Window
```

I'm running file with `powershell -command clj -M vtd.clj`
OS: Windows 10.

I tried to google, but there is no any answers on this question.
What's answer, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`project.clj` is for Leiningen, not `clj`.

Install Leiningen (if you don't have it already) and then you should be able to run `lein javac` to compile your Java source file(s) and then `lein repl` and you should be able to `(load-file "vtd.clj")`